# Firebase dynamic link URL Prefix on custom domain cannot be added

Tags: firebase

I have my custom domain connected and running (bottom 1):

[image]

When I go to my site:

```
https://mysubdomain.mysite.app/.well-known/assetlinks.json
```

I see the `assetlinks.json` being created:

```
[{"relation":["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],"target":{"namespace":"android_app","package_name":"test.mycompany","sha256_cert_fingerprints":["XX:XX:XX:XX:4B:8A:A6:53:E1:4A:82:F6:B1:48:E0:22:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:v:FD:93:XX:XX:XX:34:XX:84"]}}]
```

I removed the `mysubdomain.mysite.app` from the Dynamic Link Tab (because the links were not working) and tried to re-add it (after removing, the above json was still shown). But after re-adding this error was shown:

[image]

Am I supposed to use Filezilla and manually add a file called `assetlinks.json`? And what is the exact content of this json file? The error message talks about `firebase.json`, not `assetlinks.json`.

Answer (score 0):

I added a file called `firebase.json` with the following content:

```
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build/web",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "appAssociation": "AUTO",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      },
      {
        "source": "/<HERE_IS_MY_LINK>/**",
        "dynamicLinks": true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

It's been like a year ago that I implemented this, not sure if there is anything else missing you need to do.

Comment: But my question is: am I supposed to use Filezilla and manually add a file called assetlinks.json? The error message talks about firebase.json, not assetlinks.json. But the documentation talks about assetlinks.json.

Comment: I'm really not sure, I think you indeed need to upload it using Filezilla for instance. I'm using Firebase hosting, not sure if that makes a difference

Comment: but my assetlinks.json is completely different content. I don't think I should replace it with firebase.json. So which would be the directory of the firebase.json? https://mySubdomain.myApp.app/.well-known/firebase.json?